# Problema con express-mysql-session clearExpired

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

En mi servidor de Express guardo 2 cookies. Utilizo express-mysql-session. El problema es el siguiente, clearExpired y checkExpirationInterval no están funcionando correctamente. Una vez expirada la cookie, no se elimina automáticamente.

Configuración express-mysql-session:

```
const MYSQL_CONFIG = { host: MYSQL_HOST, user: MYSQL_USER, password: MYSQL_PASSWORD, database: MYSQL_DATABASE, port: MYSQL_PORT };
const MYSQL_STORE_CONFIG = {
  ...MYSQL_CONFIG,
  clearExpired: true,
  checkExpirationInterval: 3000
};
```

Configuración del servidor

```
const session = require("express-session");
const MySQLStore = require("express-mysql-session")(session);
const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(MYSQL_STORE_CONFIG);
const app = express();
app.use(
  session({
    secret: SESSION_TOKEN,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
      usuario: {
        name: "usuario",
        secure: false, 
        maxAge: 36000000,
        sameSite: "Strict"
      },
      usuario: {
        name: "recovery",
        secure: false, 
        maxAge: 6000,
        expires: 6000,
        sameSite: "Strict"
      },
    },
  })
);
```

maxAge: 6000 -> está puesto en 6 segundos para facilitar el testeo de clearExpired.

Row de la sesión:

```
{
session_id: yOb7kbwAQeRNDMqEPSExrUXLuJW21woB,
expires: 1705041526,
data:{"cookie":
           {"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},
            "recovery":{"token":"fff0545b2517956e159258c9951a4192d85436c0","id_usuario":"1"}
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución analizando 'data'. Básicamente el json cookie necesita un valor para la key expires. para que sea personalizando según cada cookie, seteo de la siguiente manera.

Configuración del servidor

```
const session = require("express-session");
const MySQLStore = require("express-mysql-session")(session);
const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(MYSQL_STORE_CONFIG);
const app = express();
app.use(
  session({
    secret: SESSION_TOKEN,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
      usuario: {
        name: "usuario",
        secure: false, 
        maxAge: 36000000,
        sameSite: "Strict",
      },
      usuario: {
        name: "recovery",
        secure: false, 
        maxAge: 6000,
        sameSite: "Strict"
      },
    },
  })
);
```

Seteo de cookies:

```
const generarRecuperacion = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const token = '123';
    req.session.cookie.expires = 3000;
    req.session.recovery = { token: token, id_usuario: req.params.id };
    res.status(200).json({ status: "SUCCESS" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

Otro ejemplo de seteo de cookie con diferente tiempo de expiración:

```
const iniciarSesion = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const sesion = await usuariosService.iniciarSesion(req.body);
    req.session.cookie.expires = 36000;
    req.session.usuario = sesion;
    res.status(200).send(sesion);
  } catch (error) {
    consolaUtil.logMessageToConsole(error.message);
    res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```